# Did this analogue computer from 1960 really have Internet?

Tags: history, network, early-computer, analogue-computer

If you zoom in this image, to the leftmost, white "cell" in the middle "row" of the machine, it says, in the bottom, "**INT NET**": https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/PACE-TR-10_analog_computer_-_National_Cryptologic_Museum_-_DSC07908.JPG

Does this in any way have something to do with Internet or any other kind of network? In the Wikipedia article, it says is was the first desktop computer, used by NSA.

Comment: There's no such thing as a stupid question.

Comment: A pure analogue computer with internet access would be interesting -- TCP/IP done entirely in (non-digital) circuitry!

Comment: Considering the term "internet" wasn't invented until December, 1974, I find that highly doubtful.

Comment: @MarkWilliams True, but there are such things as a non-researched question, for which there is a _downvote_ button.

Comment: Sometimes words or phrases get written down in obscure places before someone else happens to coin the same words or phrases in a way that catches on.  There is a pinball machine, for example, in which the player attempts to spell the words "STAR TREK", has nothing to do with the television show that would debut a few years after the pinball machine.  I find appearances of modern words or phrases in old artifacts is interesting, even when coincidental.

Comment: @another-dave -- you can do TCP/IP without any circuitry, see e.g. RFC1149 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1149)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, But "internet" did not mean _The_ Internet in 1974. _The_ Internet was not called by that name until some time in the 1980s.

Comment: While it is a case of (semi)convergent evolution ---"INT(er)NET" is not Internet--- it is great fun to see the apparent anachronism, even if you have to squint to read it that way.  I worked for EAI (the manufacturer of the PACE-TR-10) in the 1980s, seeing their equipment remembered is always a pleasure..

Answer (score 18):

No, this has nothing to do with any networks; the "INT" stands for "[integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrator)." That panel and the adjacent one to the right are the interface to an integrator/memory module:

[image: Integrator/memory module]

Integrators in analogue computers are used to measure quantity over time, basically a sort of sum function.

You can find more pictures of the modules on The Analog Computer Museum's [EAI TR-10 page](http://www.analogmuseum.org/english/collection/eai/tr10/); they also have [a brochure](http://www.analogmuseum.org/library/eai_tr-10.pdf) (PDF) that gives a much more detailed description of the system.

Comment: Looking at p. 8 of the brochure, this is not a complete integrator, but only a (dual) integrator network; hence the "INT NET" label. To create an integrator, it needs to be connected to an operational amplifier, which at the time meant another module of the same size.